# Asynctask closing before loading URL

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use Asynctask to first check if website is accessible and then open it. The problem is the progress dialog closes before the website is fully loaded.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private final static String TAG = "MusicFXActivityBrowser";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void readWebpage(View v){

     final Intent intent = getIntent();
     final String urlString = intent.getDataString();
     try {
         final WebView webView = new WebView(this);
         final URL url = new URL("http://india-aviation.in/users/userregister/Registration.html");
         new LoadURLTask(webView).execute(url);
     } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException " + urlString);
     }

}


/**
 * ASync Task that checks if the site is reachable and then loads the URL.
 */
private class LoadURLTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Boolean> {
    final WebView mWebView;
    String mURLString;
    // Experiment STARTS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait...");

 // Experiment ENDS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public LoadURLTask(final WebView webView) {
        mWebView = webView;
    }
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final URL... urls) {
        final URL url = urls[0];
        mURLString = url.toString();
        boolean isSiteReachable = false;
        final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
        try {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            final int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                isSiteReachable = true;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to " + mURLString);
        }
        return isSiteReachable;
    }
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean isReachable) {
        if (isReachable) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            setContentView(mWebView);
            mWebView.loadUrl(mURLString);
        } else {
            createAndShowNetworkDialog();
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Shows the network dialog alerting the user that the net is down.
 */
private void createAndShowNetworkDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.browser_error_dialog_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.browser_error_dialog_text)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).show();
}
```

}

Comment: obviously you should use some event which is fired when webview loads the whole page ... asked bazillion times how to achive this

Comment: `setContentView(mWebView); mWebView.setMagicEvent_DoSomeReaserchToFindRealName(new SomeListener_Again_do_someReaserch() { void somthingLikeUrlLoadedOrPageReady_please_dont_be_lazy() { dissmis_here() }); mWebView.loadUrl(mURLString);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The dialog is closing before loading of website because you are executing `dismiss()` before `setContentView`

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean isReachable) {
        if (isReachable) {
        // diaplay website first
        setContentView(mWebView);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mURLString);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
             // cancel the dialog and website is also launched
               dialog.dismiss();
         }
         },2000 /* delay of 2 seconds */);

    } else {
        createAndShowNetworkDialog();
    }
}
```

I have suggested **alternate** way that **you can first display website and when website is launching in screen, wait for 2 seconds and close the dialog then**. This approach will not fail in case website launch delayed and your application **UI will give correct behaviour**

Comment: still not working. Progress dialog disappears and then there is blank screen and then page loads.

Comment: Yes, I tried 8000 and it nearly works for this link. But I need to change the timing for different links. Is there no way to close it automatically using same code?

Comment: Add some average delay common and check.. like 8000 ms seems fine.. I have also editted my answer

Comment: @Selvin: better you answer this question with your logic

Comment: @somnathpal: If this answer is usefull to your error solution, please accept and let other know about it

Comment: I would say your solution works in a way, so I would definitely accept it. Though I have found a different code for Asynctask which works better.